# can't add maven to eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I added the maven plugin for eclipse Via the install software feature. In looking through some docs on how to set it up to actually work i have to create a String substitution that points to mvn.bat . then i have to create an external tool that uses this string substitution. the issue is that i can't find mvn.bat on my machine. If i right click on my project folder and go to 
`Run As--> Run Configurations --> Maven Build` is now an option but i can't find maven.bat... are my directions old or do i need to download something else?

---

so it looks like i have maven installed but i am missing a step in set up. I can't find the .bat file and get errors in my app in eclipse (indigo). I just discovered that I can use the project ok in spring source tool suite. so i will just use that.

thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I believe the answer is yes. Like i said i can go to run as --> etc and maven is now an option. How would i be able to confirm? if i run mvn at command line it isn't recognized but would i have to be in directory with mvn.bat to run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which plugin did you install? You should install [m2e](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/download/) from: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases . It comes with an embedded maven so you don´t need to do any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your PATH environment variable with the directory you installed maven to.

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-windows/

Comment: This answer assumes windows, because of the maven.bat mention.

Comment: thanks. if i downloaded maven via the install software feature do you know what the home directory would be. something under C:\Program Files\eclipse\plugins ?

Answer (score 0):

As Fabricio said, you should install the [m2e](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases) plugin in your Eclipse (if it's not already installed). This installs the support to manage Maven projects and also installs an instance of Maven in your Eclipse Plugins.

If you go to Eclipse / Preferences you'll see a Maven option. There you will the Installations section, where you can either use the Maven version that came with the plugin or your own installation, even configuring which settings.xml file do you want to use.